# Python Process.join is Released in Linux but Not Windows

Tags: python, linux, windows, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have observed different behavior in how Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 handle the `Process.join()` function. What accounts for the difference in behavior?

I am running Python 3.6.

In this code, the main process starts a subprocess and then calls `join`. The subprocess runs a thread and does not terminate it. In Windows, the join continues to block, and the main process runs forever. In Linux, the subprocess ends and the main process ends.

The `print(thread)` line shows that the thread is not daemonic on either Windows or Linux. I do not specify whether the child process is created with `fork` or `spawn`.

```py
import threading
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

def thread_f():
    print("Thread function")
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)

def subprocess_f():
    print("TOP of Subprocess function")
    thread = threading.Thread(target=thread_f)
    thread.start()
    threads = ', '.join(map(str, [(thread.name, thread.ident, "isDaemon {}".format(thread.isDaemon())) for thread in
                                  threading.enumerate()]))
    print(threads)
    print("BOTTOM of Subprocess function")

def main():
    print("TOP of main")
    process = Process(target=subprocess_f)
    process.start()
    process.join()
    print("BOTTOM of main")

# In Windows 10, main process continues to run.
# In Ubuntu Linux 18.04, main process ends.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output In Windows:

```
TOP of main
TOP of Subprocess function
Thread function
('MainThread', 14952, 'isDaemon False'), ('Thread-1', 10992, 'isDaemon False')
BOTTOM of Subprocess function
```

Output In Linux:

```
TOP of main
TOP of Subprocess function
Thread function
('MainThread', 140283868624704, 'isDaemon False'), ('Thread-1', 140283844200192, 'isDaemon False')
BOTTOM of Subprocess function
BOTTOM of main
```

Comment: It appears that `Process.join()` on windows waits for all threads to finish in that process, while on Ubuntu it only waits for the main thread to finish. I can't find any documentation explaining this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Windows and linux use different worker start method by default.

Using `spawn` relies on the child process terminating gracefully, which happens after the thread in the worker terminates, because the thread in child process is not daemonic. This happens on windows.

Using `fork` causes python to call [`os._exit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os._exit) in the main thread after the function finishes to avoid freeing resources in the parent process, which causes it to terminate abruptly and not wait for child threads. Which happens on linux.

think of "freeing resources" like closing servers, not a simple memory deallocation.

You can use `spawn` on linux to get consistent behaviour using [multiprocessing.set_start_method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.set_start_method), or you can call `os._exit` yourself on windows.

Comment: I confirm that Linux exhibits the same behavior as Windows when subprocesses are created with `spawn`, e.g. `multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')`. I also confirm that Windows exhibits the same behavior as Linux when the subprocess ends with `os._exit(0)`