# Thread started from a process stops too soon

Tags: python, multithreading, process, raspberry-pi

I'm currently trying to synchronize a recording system where we have 3 Raspberry pi, each connected to an RGBD camera.

Each time an RPi is sending a frame, it's supposed to be received in a thread associated with a function recv_data, and the frame received is saved in a separate thread associated with a function save. Since we are using 3 RPi, 6 threads are created. I thought I could optimize it by running each combo receive/save thread in different processes, but I don't know why, the threads stop at the first loop of "while True" since I made this change (it was running correctly when there was no process). Any idea about what could be wrong in my code?

```
def recv_data(socket, display_title, q_color, q_depth, q_timestamps):
    # i is the frames counter
    i = 1

    print('Receiving frames from ' + display_title)

    while True:
        # receive color_image, depth_image and timestamp
        color_msg, depth_msg, timestamp = socket.recv_multipart()

        # decompress qoi
        color_msg = qoi.decode(color_msg)

        # convert and reshape images and decode timestamp to string
        color_frame = np.frombuffer(color_msg, 'uint8')
        depth_frame = np.frombuffer(depth_msg, 'uint16')
        timestamp = timestamp.decode()

        print(display_title)

        q_color.put(color_frame)
        q_depth.put(depth_frame)
        q_timestamps.put(timestamp)

        # increment index
        i = i + 1


# thread to save the frames from color frames and depth frames global lists
def save(display_title, q_color, q_depth, q_timestamps):
    i = 1

    while True:
        if not q_color.empty():

            # save images in numpy array
            path = frame_path + '/' + display_title + '/'
            save_frame(q_color.get(), 'color', path, i)
            save_frame(q_depth.get(), 'depth', path, i)

            # save timestamp in csv file
            csv1 = frame_path + '/' + display_title.replace(" ", "") + '.csv'
            data = open(csv1, 'a', newline='')
            writer_data = csv.writer(data)
            save_timestamp(writer_data, q_timestamps.get(), i)

            # increment counter
            i = i + 1


# Acquisition function
def start_acquisition():
    # connect server to client
    socket1 = server_connect('tcp://192.168.1.150:5551', 'RPi1')
    socket2 = server_connect('tcp://192.168.1.144:5552', 'RPi2')
    socket3 = server_connect('tcp://192.168.1.169:5553', 'RPi3')

    # initiate csv file for timestamps
    file_name = frame_path + '/RPi1.csv'
    open(file_name, 'w').close()
    file_name = frame_path + '/RPi2.csv'
    open(file_name, 'w').close()
    file_name = frame_path + '/RPi3.csv'
    open(file_name, 'w').close()

    p1 = Process(target=start_acquisition_threads, args=(socket1, "RPi 1"))
    p2 = Process(target=start_acquisition_threads, args=(socket2, "RPi 2"))
    p3 = Process(target=start_acquisition_threads, args=(socket3, "RPi 3"))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()


def start_acquisition_threads(socket, rpi):
    # define queues to manage frames and timestamps
    q_color = Queue()
    q_depth = Queue()
    q_timestamps = Queue()

    # create and start threads
    th_recv_data = Thread(target=recv_data, args=(socket, rpi, q_color, q_depth, q_timestamps))
    th_save_data = Thread(target=save, args=(rpi,q_color, q_depth, q_timestamps))

    th_recv_data.start()
    th_save_data.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to join the created threads in the child process to prevent python from terminating the child process when the function ends (which kills the extra threads)

```py
th_recv_data = Thread(target=recv_data, args=(socket, rpi, q_color, q_depth, q_timestamps))
th_save_data = Thread(target=save, args=(rpi,q_color, q_depth, q_timestamps))

th_recv_data.start()
th_save_data.start()

th_recv_data.join()
th_save_data.join()
```

For anyone wondering why you need to do that with multiprocessing, it's a multiprocessing [implementation detail on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75805054/python-process-join-is-released-in-linux-but-not-windows/75809299#75809299).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already tried that before, but the problem was still here.