# Python process.join(timeout=x) never times out

Tags: python, multiprocessing, timeout, pypdf

I'm having a problem using the process timeout in Python 3.10.

I've been building a small tool to search a series of PDF files for certain keywords, and found that some PDF pages would cause the PyPDF extracttext() function to hang endlessly, with no return or errors.

After searching for solutions, about all I found were suggestions to use multiprocessing.Process to spawn the subroutine as a separate process, and use **process.join(timeout=x)** to limit how long the subprocess was allowed to run.

I implemented this, but the subprocess still hangs forever when it hits one of the problem PDF pages.

Further searching lead me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75805054/python-process-join-is-released-in-linux-but-not-windows) , which seemed like a possibility, since I am running under Windows.  But adding **os._exit(0)** to the end of my OpenPDF subroutine failed to make any difference.

My multiprocessing "call":

```
if __name__=='__main__':
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=OpenPDF(FileName, chSearchString, LogFile))
        process.daemon= True
        process.start()
        process.join(timeout=5)
        if process.is_alive:
            print(f"OpenPDF hung on file {FileName}{chNewLine}")
            process.terminate()
            print(f"OpenPDF Terminated after timeout on {FileName}{chNewLine}")
```

The call to OpenPDF works, and my print statements inside OpenPDF shows that it opens the PDF source and advances successfully until it hits the page that causes the hangup.

This is my my first attempt at multiprocessing, so I may be overlooking something very basic.  I'm not attempting to speed up the code through parallel processes (though that might be fun to try later), but just to prevent my script from hanging forever when **PyPDF.gettext** hangs.

I've been unable to find any sources that suggest why **PyPDF.gettext** seems to be immune to the process timeout, or how to go about troubleshooting when **Process.join(timeout=x)** fails to time out.

Comment: You are calling OpenPDF and then creating a process on the returned object. Instead, have the subprocess do it: `process = multiprocessing.Process(target=OpenPDF, args=(FileName, chSearchString, LogFile))`. it that works, this already has answers here on SO. If that's not it, and you are on Linux, you could try a second join after the terminate and if it fails after, say, .1 seconds, you could use the .kill() method which sends SIGKILL.

Comment: No good, I'm afraid.  I changed the "process=" line as you suggested, and python halted on the "process.start" with "cannot pickle '_io.TextIOWrapper' object".  Even more oddly, making that change caused the *main* routine to *repeat* and try running a second time from the entry point while the error was still active.

Comment: That may be LogFile. If you want to open a log, you may be best off opening it in the subprocess. So, some other worker that then calls OpenPDF.

Comment: Its actually working better than before. Your programs was hanging before ever calling `multiprocessing.Process`. We've kicked the can further down the road.

Comment: It's *not* working better than before.  Now, OpenPDF is not getting called at all, and somehow the multiprocess call is now causing the "main" routine (which is a single-pass, no-loop routine) to be called from the entry point multiple times.

Comment: It does appear to be the LogFile argument.  If I eliminate that, I don't get the "pickle" error anymore.  Now to figure out how to have a log file both my Main routine and subroutines can write to.  (Note, the LogFile variable is the returned "handle" from a File Open operation)

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser.  My Main begins with a tkinter askdirectory dialog box, which works fine.  And it's only called once, at the beginning of Main, outside of any loop structures.  But now that the Multiprocess with timeout appears to be working okay, I'm seeing something strange:  every time the multiprocess timeout happens, that tkinter dialog opens again... but then closes itself on the next timeout event.  Then re-opens again.  Since MP is only pointing at my OpenPDF subroutine, there really shouldn't be any way for MP to "recurse" Main.  Really doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Well, spoke too soon.  The multiprocess call never actually *calls* OpenPDF.  Somehow, the MP is recursing my Main routine endlessly.  By single-stepping in VS Code, every time the Process.join() executes, the program pointer jumps back to the first line of the Main routine.

Comment: If multiprocessing spawns on your system (Windows and macos) then it could be that `mp.Process` reloads your main .py file. You need to protect all of your main code needs to be protected with a `if __name__=='__main__':` block. Python will import the module with OpenPDF, and that means everything at module level runs. Its a good idea to put multiprocessing functions in their own module outside of gui stuff when possible.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand what you mean.  I can see I have some studying to do, as my Python-fu does not yet include writing/calling multiple modules.  And to think, all I wanted was a way to kill PyPDF if it hung too long!  :P

Comment: Progress!  Moving the "If name=main" test to the very top of the main routine fixed the issue where MultiProcess seemed to be jumping the program pointer back to the entry point.  However, now it seems like the MP timeout timer doesn't reset -- even when the PyPDF library doesn't hang, the Timeout still trips every X seconds and whichever file was being searched gets skipped and the program moves on to the next file.  Obviously MP has subtleties I haven't yet grasped.  Well, back to the autodidactic classroom....